# How to split string of characters by commas but keep dates?

Tags: r, string, csv, arr

I have a string of characters like this in R

```
ABCDE,"January 10, 2010",F,,,,GH,"March 9, 2009",,,
```

I would like to do something like `str.split()` to partition by all combinations of commas and quotation marks into an array of strings, but keep the commas in quotation marks that represent dates so that I get:

```
ABCDE
January 10, 2010
F
GH
March 9, 2009
```

Thanks

Comment: If you dates are in every case double quoted, you can parse them with `regmatches( data,gregexec('"([^"]*)"|([^,]*),?', data))`. Second and third row will contain the unquoted results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is as showed, then a regex option would be to create delimiter and make use of `read.table`

```
read.table(text = gsub('"', '', gsub('("[^,"]+,)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,',
   '\n', trimws(gsub(",{2,}", ",", str1), whitespace = ","), perl = TRUE)), 
    header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, sep = "\n")
```

-output

```
                V1
1            ABCDE
2 January 10, 2010
3                F
4               GH
5    March 9, 2009
```

---

Or with `scan`

```
data.frame(V1 = setdiff(scan(text = str1, sep = ",",
    what = character()), ""))
```

-output

```
              V1
1            ABCDE
2 January 10, 2010
3                F
4               GH
5    March 9, 2009
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "ABCDE,\"January 10, 2010\",F,,,,GH,\"March 9, 2009\",,,"
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this to be the simplest approach!

Comment: @Ed_Gravy I think AndreWildberg solution is much better than mine, if the OP is marking solution, please do it to that one.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach

```
data.frame(list = na.omit(
  unname(unlist(read.csv(
    text = 'ABCDE,"January 10, 2010",F,,,,GH,"March 9, 2009",,,', 
    check.names = F, header = F)))))
              list
1            ABCDE
2 January 10, 2010
3            FALSE
4               GH
5    March 9, 2009
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be using a CSV parser here, but if you wanted to use a pure regex approach you could try:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

x <- "ABCDE,\"January 10, 2010\",F,,,,GH,\"March 9, 2009\",,,"
y <- str_match_all(x, "\"(.*?)\"|[^,]+")[[1]]
output <- coalesce(y[,2], y[,1])
output

[1] "ABCDE"            "January 10, 2010" "F"                "GH"
[5] "March 9, 2009"
```

The regex pattern uses an alternation trick and says to match:

- `"(.*?)"` match a date in quotes, but don't capture the quotes
- `|` OR
- `[^,]+` match single CSV term

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
na.omit(stack(read.csv(text = str1, header = FALSE)))[1]

            values
1            ABCDE
2 January 10, 2010
3            FALSE
4               GH
5    March 9, 2009
```

---

```
txt <- 'ABCDE,"January 10, 2010",F,,,,GH,"March 9, 2009",,,'
```